# F# map to C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, f#

I'm trying to convert an F# map to a C# dictionary, so far I am using:

```
    let toDictionary (map : Map<_, _>) : Dictionary<_, _> =
        let dict = new Dictionary<_, _>()
        map |> Map.iter (fun k v -> dict.Add(k, v))
        dict
```

It just feels a little clunky, I'm quite new to F# so it there a better way?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**1. If you want the standard Dictionary implementation:** [See the answer of jbtule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27109405/4191347)

**2. If you want an immutable, fast IDictionary:** [the dict function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353774.aspx) from the current F# core library allows to create a read-only dictionary from any sequence of key-value tuples:

```
myDict |> Map.toSeq |> dict
```

The return value has type `IDictionary` and should thus be usable from C#. *Thanks to [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27109880/4191347) for reminding me of Map.toSeq.*

**3. If you're fine with using Map directly**: Map<,> implements IDictionary, which should be convenient to use from C#. However, access of a map is O(log n), while hash-based dictionary access is constant order.

Comment: Summarizing others' answers FTW.

Comment: @Daniel I'm not sure if this is sarcastic or not. Reformulation is encouraged; also, I first used dict and later first proposed direct usage of the Map type, so it's not even "only" a summary. Either way, I meant no disrespect. I upvoted jbtule's answer immediately, and if you add a note or warning on immutability, I'll upvote yours as well. (I hesitated since people might expect the result to be mutable and then get an exception at run-time)

Comment: Actually `dict` doesn't give you a c# dictionary, the following returns false `(Map.empty<int,string> |> Map.toSeq |> dict) :? Dictionary<int,string>` So the question is why would you want to use it over your answer of *use it directly* for this question.

Comment: @jbtule Because it is faster. As I noted above, dict returns something that has O(1) access but is still immutable. So if the OP happens to need something that is immutable and has fast access, but doesn't have to be the `Collections.Generic.Dictionary<,>` implementation, this seems a better choice.

Comment: "So if the OP happens to need something that has O(1)" This phrase demonstrates the kitchen sinking going on in this answer. The question is F# map -> C# dictionary, not F# map -> F# constant time lookup datastructure.

Comment: Also in regards to the comment by @Daniel about summarizing other's answer, while citing other answers is encouraged, not in the same question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269396/copy-pasting-the-contents-another-answer-to-the-same-question-with-attribution

Comment: @jbtule No doubt, your answer is the best single response. But interpreting "C# dictionary" as `IDictionary<,>` is both a reasonable and more general, so the other answers are not wrong. (Besides, people searching for this might not *really* want what they *think* they want, so some extra information doesn't hurt.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65545/discussion-between-vandroiy-and-jbtule).

Comment: Removed my version of jbtule's answer but left the link as discussed in chat. Though this is not demanded by the rules, unless I had copy-pasted it without modifications. See here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251390/4191347

Answer (score 17):

A C# `Dictionary` will take an `IDictionary` in it's constructor. `Map` is an `IDictionary` so:

```
let toDictionary (map : Map<_, _>) : Dictionary<_, _> = Dictionary(map)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
let toDictionary = Map.toSeq >> dict
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot about Map.toSeq. Note though that this dictionary will throw an exception on changes, which may or may not be what the OP wants. (Thanks; I edited my answer to use toSeq as well since the earlier version of that solution was just worse)

Comment: While this doesn't actually return a C# Dictionary. It does return a structure with underlying Dictionary characteristics, and using the function composition operator makes it very clean.