# Converting complex Map data structure to F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am pretty new to the language F#, let alone functional programming, and I am having trouble implementing a Map data structure. The C# type equivalent of this Map would be:

```
var map = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Tuple<char, Tuple<int, int>[]>[]>>();
```

I've tried to implement this myself and searching online, but my inexperience with the language is letting me down.

Is anyone able to show me:

1. An immutable implementation of this structure
2. A mutable implementation

Comment: What particular point are you stuck on?  Can you not get the existing types to work or are you trying to create your own?

Comment: @JohnPalmer I'm more stuck on the syntax more than anything. I can make a map, I can make a list, and a tuple, but not all of them interwoven in this structure.

Comment: Can you show some of your attempts? Or explain what you want to do in plain English? Or, perhaps, at least show equivalent C# or VB code?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin the C# line I posted above is what I want to achieve in F#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example like this:

```
let t1 = (2,3)
let t2 = ("a",t1)
let m1 = Map([1,t2])
let m2 = Map([2,m1])
```

The signature of this is:

```
val it : Map<int,Map<int,(string * (int * int))>> = map [(2, map [(1, ("a", (2, 3)))])]
```

This is using lists not array.

For the mutable part you already show the implementation. Just use

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
```

Not sure but maybe this is helpful for you: [F# map to C# Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109142/f-map-to-c-sharp-dictionary)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have some queries about the code you posted: 1) I am trying to associate a list of (int * int) to a single char in a list, are you able to update your answer to accommodate this if you could, 2) How would I go about initialising a default value where the first map has a value of an empty map?

Comment: I think I figured out what I wanted based on this answer, thank you very much!

Comment: you can do `Map.empty<int,(string * (int * int))>` and for 1) put the tuple in a list. Ah, sorry, you were faster then me. Sure.

Answer (score 4):

The mere translation is pretty straightforward:

- `Dictionary` either becomes `Map` (if you want an immutable structure) or stays as it is (if you want mutability)
- `Tuple<a, b>` becomes `a * b` in the type declaration, and `(x, y)` in the variable usage.

Hence, if we go with immutability, we get:

```
Map<int, Map<int, (string * (int * int)[])[]>>
```

But that's, quite frankly, unreadable. Fortunately, F# has the perfect solution for this: [type abbreviations](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-abbreviations/).

That complex type can be decomposed into a bunch of *aliases*, or *abbreviations*, which express the problem domain more clearly to a human reader. For example, you could have:

```ml
type Cell = int * int

type Zone = Cell []

type Battleship = string * Zone

type Flotilla = Battleship []

type TaskForce = Map<int, Flotilla>

type Fleet = TaskForce []

type NavalTheater = Map<int, Fleet>
```

which is the exact same type as above, but it's a *lot* more readable, for most use cases. And it has *zero* overhead, as the abbreviations will be simply replaced with the native types during compilation.