# F# Basics: Map of Maps?

Tags: dictionary, f#

My professor has given our class hints on solving a problem and has proposed we firstly model our class using:

```
let students = Map.add 1 Map.empty Map.empty
```

The world starts of with one student (indicated by their ID e.g 1), each student has many class ID's each having a Grade (A+,F etc) associated with them.

I'm having trouble understanding what this code actually means, I understand a single map. For example

```
let student = Map.add 43 "A+"
```

How do actually add a new 'student' or 'classID/grade' to the proposed version and return a new Map?

As a followup how would I access/iterate over elements over a map like this?
Thanks, functional programming beginner here and really struggling.

Comment: Would this get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393127/converting-complex-map-data-structure-to-f/36393396#36393396

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword btw.

Comment: oh whoops, thanks.

Comment: are you sure this line is what you think it is: `let student = Map.add 43 "A+" `

Comment: @s952163 Sorry it should probably be `let student = Map.add 43 "A+" Map.empty` which returns a new map, the key being 43 and the value being A+. But I need a map of maps I think. So it would be Map.add 1 (Map.add 43 "A+"). So it would be a map whose value is a map, not sure on the syntax or how to add to it, or how to actually access it

Comment: It doesn't make a map :) What do you think the difference is between these two: `let students = Map.add 43 "A+" ` and `Map.empty.Add(43, "A+")` (since you started with Map.empty). Can you see the type signiture?

Comment: yes. exactly. But you won't be adding it to an empty map all the time. You would be adding it back to the students map if you want to grow. So once know how to add to map, what stops you from adding a map, where the key is the student id, and the value is another map, with the key as a class, and the value of the grade? If this is too long we can take it to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f

Comment: @s952163 hey sorry, I don't have enough rep to chat yet. But I think I understand it now. Thanks for your help you made it click :)

Comment: now you have enough reputation ;)

Comment: @FoggyFinder thanks! :)

Comment: Since you noted that this is for a class, the people at the F# tag have no problem helping, however sometimes students will seek a final answer which is of no benefit to the student and actually unfair to others in the class, If you could provide a link to the assignments then we can be aware of them and avoid giving out final answers. :)

Comment: Hey guy coder, sorry we aren't allowed to link school assignments. The actual assignment question is alot different to the one I posted,  it has nothing to do with students or classes, just a similar data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let grades = Map.empty<string,string>
let students = Map.empty<int,Map<string,string>>
let students = students.Add(1,grades.Add("class1","A").Add("class2","B"))
let students = students.Add(2,grades.Add("class3","A").Add("class4","C"))
```

you can access the value by indexing into the map:
`students.[1]` will return `val it : Map<string,string> = map [("class1", "A"); ("class2", "B")]`

Two other comments: 1) Generally you would build some sort of data structure first, for example a list of tuples, and build the map from there.

```
let classes = [("class1","A");("class2","B")]
classes |> Map.ofList
```

2) you can iterate over the map by Map.iter or Map.map:

```
let classes' = classes |> Map.ofList
```

and prevent grade inflation :-)

```
classes' |> Map.map (fun key value -> (key,value+"-"))
```

Please take a look at: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Sets_and_Maps and 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353880.aspx

Comment: Great :) this is what I was looking for, thank you so much, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured out how to add to it, I just needed to give each Map a table name for example

```
let students = Map.add 1 (Map.add 43 "A+" Map.empty) Map.empty
```

And I can just use `Let student1 = Map.find 1 students` to get the map of a particular student.

Comment: yes. but one particular feature of Map that it is immutable. And I assume you want to be adding to your map. Let me another answer as well.

Comment: @s952163 I have to have one version which is immutable (I have this half implemented) using fold and one mutable which is meant to show the performance difference. Sorry I'm a newb how do I let you another answer?

Comment: I added another answer and some clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Although I could understand the answer, I had a syntax error when trying the answer from s952163 (duplicate variable declaration), so thought I'd post an alternative that may help.

Hopefully the comments in the code explain the advice.

```
// Alias the types for ease of use later
let studentRecords = Map.empty<int, Map<string, string>>
let grades = Map.empty<string, string>

// create a collection of students 
// (note use of aliases here but could use Map.empty<>.Add if preferred)
let students = 
    studentRecords
        .Add(1, grades.Add("class1", "A").Add("class2", "B"))
        .Add(2, grades.Add("class1", "D").Add("class2", "C"))

// can index into the student map by the integer key
// and print out the value of the embedded map based on it's key
let studentId = 1
let className = "class2"
let student1 = students.[studentId]

printfn 
    "StudentId: %i obtained %s in %s" 
    studentId 
    student1.[className] 
    className

// can use Map.map to iterate and obtain some specifics from the embedded map
// eg.  This prints out all students and their grades for "class2"
printfn "%s results:" className
students 
    |> Map.map (fun key value -> printfn "Student %i - %s" key value.[className] )
```

I have just started f# too, so the answer from s952163 really helped me get to the above.  Hope it adds further insight to someone coming to this question.

Comment: Thanks for the extra input, is a big help

Comment: values are immutable in F# (unless decorated with  `mutable`) but you should be able to shadow variables (assign new variable to the old name). This probably happens if you execute it as a block in FSI for example. You can wrap it in a function.

Comment: Yup.  Spot on, I've been using FSI entirely so far.  <wanders off to look up "shadowing" in the docs>  thanks for the extra!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question what `let student = Map.add 43 "A+"` means: `Map.add` takes 3 arguments, a key, a value, and a map to which to add. `student` is hence a function that takes a map, and returns a new map that also contains a key `43` with value `"A+"`

Another suggestion regarding datatypes: Grades are not free-form strings. You can make your code safer by using a datatype that closely matches the domain. For example, for grades, you can use

```
type Grade = 
    | APlus
    | A
    | B
    | F // Omitting the other grades for brevity
```

If you do that and use pattern matching well, the compiler will help you a great deal with checking your code for corner-cases that you may have overlooked. Similarly, you can avoid mixing up integers that identify students with integers that identify classes.

```
[<Measure>]
type StudentID
[<Measure>]
type ClassID
// A class that contains 2 students with IDs 1 and 2
let initialClass = Set.ofList [ 1<StudentID>; 2<_> ]
// Adding a student with ID 3 gives a new class
let classWithNewStudent = initialClass.Add 3<_>
```

Note that you only need to add type annotation at one place, and you can use `<_>` throughout the rest. This is not fool-proof of course - you could still do `1<StudentID> + 2<StudentID>`, but at least you are prevented from indexing a per-class map with a student ID.

With that in place, you can now build up maps for the grades within a class:

```
let gradesForClass101 = 
    [ (1<StudentID>, APlus); (2<_>, F) ]
    |> Map.ofList

let gradesForClass206 = 
    [ (3<StudentID>, B); (2<_>, F) ]
    |> Map.ofList
// Here's the student function from your question:
let addStudent43 = Map.add 43<_> APlus
// This is now a new map that contains students 2, 3, 43
let moreGrades = addStudent43 gradesForClass206
```

With the within-class maps in place, you can now define a map from classID to studentID to grade:

```
// This is now a map of maps: For each class, we store 
// a mapping classID -> grades that all students got in this class
let gradesPerClass = 
    [ (206<ClassID>, gradesForClass206); (101<_>, gradesForClass101)]
    |> Map.ofList
```

You were also asking about mutable/immutable in one of your comments - not completely sure what the ask was, but here are two ways of accumulating grades for a student ID 2, with immutable and mutable data structures:

```
// Compute all grades that student 2 gets
let gradesViaFold = 
    gradesPerClass
    |> Map.fold (fun state _ grades ->
        // We don't need the classID here, so use _ as the second arg
        match grades.TryFind 2<_> with
        // We found a grade for student 2: Add it at the beginning of the list
        | Some grade -> grade :: state
        // Student 2 did not get a grade for this class: leave the state
        // (grades seen so far) empty
        | _ -> state
    ) []
let printGrades g = Seq.iter (printfn "Grade %A") g
do printGrades gradesViaFold

// Compute all grades that student 2 gets, via a mutable list
let gradesMutable = System.Collections.Generic.List<Grade>()
do 
    gradesPerClass
    |> Map.iter (fun _ grades ->
        match grades.TryFind 2<_> with
        | Some grade -> gradesMutable.Add grade
        | _ -> ()
    )
    printGrades gradesMutable
```

(using `do` just to highlight the parts with side-effects, this is not needed in most cases)

Here's another example of how to go through maps:

```
// A map from classID to grade for student 2
let gradesForStudent2 = 
    gradesPerClass
    |> Seq.choose (fun (KeyValue(classID, grades)) -> 
        match grades.TryFind 2<_> with
        | Some grade -> Some (classID, grade)
        | _ -> None
    )
    |> Map.ofSeq
```