# f# dictionary, immutability and performance

Tags: dictionary, f#

I am porting C# code to F# and I have a situation with some rather large, but simple dictionaries; they're value is a single float and the key is a string.

The code processes commands that require to insert, delete but also update some keys and there are a lot of operations happening constantly (it is tracking trading order books).

I'm quite new at F# and I'm trying to understand something. From what I read, the F# dictionaries are immutable, so any change would rebuild the dictionary.

If I have a dictionary with 1000 entries and I do 200 changes in it, does that mean that the dictionary's data gets rebuild 200 times?

If this is not the right collection, in F#, what else should I use for a quite large list that changes many times per second? (the data is [string] = float)

Comment: I wonder whether DictionarySlim is what you're after? https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections/Microsoft/Collections/Extensions/DictionarySlim.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` class is identical between F# and C# (it's the exact same thing).  If that works for you in C#, it should work perfectly well for you in F#, using precisely the same method calls.  This interoperability with other .NET languages is a good aspect of F#.  F# for Fun and Profit has [some info on porting from C# to F#](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/porting-from-csharp.html).

The confusion likely arises because you are looking at discussions of F#'s [built-in `Map` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.map%5B%27key%2C%27value%5D-class-%5Bfsharp%5D), which does much the same thing but is F#-specific and 'immutable' (I'm pretty sure it is a [persistent data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure), meaning that you don't have to entirely chuck out the old one to create a new version).

See [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/#what-collection-do-i-want) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109142/f-map-to-c-sharp-dictionary) for a bit more of a Dictionary vs Map discussion - turns out there's actually C# dictionaries, F# dictionaries and F# maps, apparently.

All this being said, using strings as keys in a dictionary doesn't sound like a particularly great idea to me in performance terms, though I'm failing to come up with a suitable replacement if there is a potentially unbounded set of keys possible.

Comment: I was reading about F# dictionaries there: https://www.dotnetperls.com/dict-fs
so are they a different things from maps altogether? for the original question, I will use the same .net type. Regarding the string keys, they're kind of mini-guids coming from the broker. the only optimization would be to tailor the hashing function to these.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like that site might have conflated Maps and Dicts.  I'll update my answer in a moment to include some links to further information on the two.

Comment: So turns out I was partially wrong too.  There _is_ an F#-specific Dictionary type, as well as Map, apparently.  For your purposes, I would still recommend sticking with a regular `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`.

Comment: @Thomas That dotnetperls link is a bit misleading. In F#, there is no `dict` type. `dict` is just a function that creates a generic `IDictionary` from a sequence of tuples, using the standard .NET generic `Dictionary` under the hood (with some performance optimisations). If you try to modify the resulting `IDictionary` an exception is thrown, so it is "immutable", but not "persistent" in the same way that maps are.